# Do I really have to create a new docker image with 4 commands installed in this situation?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to use gitlab CI to renew SSL certificates using let's encrypt `certbot` command, and then place the certificate to multiple locations using `aws`, `jq`, and `ansible` commands.

Must I create a docker image with `certbot`, `aws`, `jq`, and `ansible` commands installed in this situation?

Is it possible to have gitlab-runner use the following 4 docker containers instead of creating a new docker image with the 4 commands installed?

1. [certbot/dns-route53](https://hub.docker.com/r/certbot/dns-route53/dockerfile)
2. [jq](https://hub.docker.com/r/imega/jq)
3. [docker-ansible](https://github.com/cytopia/docker-ansible)
4. [docker-aws](https://github.com/cgswong/docker-aws)

I know that running [docker in docker should be avoided](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/). But I got stuck on installing `certbot` command into a docker image.

Answer (score 0):

Although GitLab CI allows multiple Docker images per job, the extras can only be added as "service"s, which means you will not be able to use their CLI tools. Using Docker in Docker (dind) for this doesn't make too much sense (not to mention it's slow and error-prone). You have two options.

1. **Quick and dirty**

   Although not recommended, an easy way would be to simply create a custom Docker image containing all the four tools (as you have suggested in your post).
2. **Recommended**

   I have also run into the issue you have described. What you are supposed to do is create multiple jobs, where each job has one of the Docker images you need (e.g., `jq`). And then order the jobs in `stages`.

   Here's an example `.gitlab-ci.yml` snippet assuming that you first use `certbot` once (`certify`), and then use `aws`, `jq`, and `ansible` in any order (`deploy`):

   ```
   stages: [certify, deploy]

   generate-certificate:
     stage: certify
     image: certbot
     script: certbot create
     artifacts:
       paths: [certificate.txt]

   deply-to-aws:
     stage: deploy
     image: aws
     script: aws deploy certificate.txt
   ```

   Obviously, replace the `image`s, `script`s, etc. with the actual ones that you'll be using.